# ADB restore: how do I restore the entire backup?

Tags: adb, backup, twrp

Before flashing a custom ROM to my Nexus 5, I made a backup of system, data and cache using `adb backup --twrp`; this gave me a 17GB `backup.ab` file.

My custom ROM endeavour went wrong and now I want to restore the backup. When I try `adb restore backup.ab`, it seems to only restore the system partition and not data or cache. Output on the TWRP screen:

```
Updating partition details...
...done
Full SELinux support is present.
Wiping System
Formatting System using make_ext4fs...
Restoring System...
[System done (190 seconds)]
Restore Complete
```

It completed way too fast to have transferred all 17GB back. How do I get it to restore the entire backup?

Phone: Nexus 5 32GB, TWRP version: 3.2.1-1